# Logics and formal grammars

Tags: logic, formal-grammar

I recently came across this way of defining propositional logic:

Let $p \in PV$ be a propositional variable. The set $F$ of propositional formulas is defined by the following grammar:

$$\alpha ::= p | \top | \bot| \lnot \alpha | \alpha \supset \alpha | \alpha \lor \alpha | \alpha \land\alpha$$

I really like this representation because it is so compact and I would like to learn more about it. Can somebody tell me where to find more information about this notation? I guess it is some kind of formal grammar? Any links or textbooks are appreciated :)

Comment: This notation is called "Backus-Naur" form (often abbreviated as "BN form" or even just "BNF".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this question I quote the comment from [Andreas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/48510/andreas-blass)

> This notation is called "Backus-Naur" form (often abbreviated as "BN
>   form" or even just "BNF".